# Chrome desktop can play this .mp4 video, but Chrome mobile can not

Tags: stream, adodb

there is a .mp4 video in this url,

http://forum.tinnitus-light.org/topic_933_1.html

Chrome desktop can play this .mp4 video, but Chrome mobile can not and tips 'sorry, this video cannot play', I have no idea about this...

more info about this video is this file does not storage in server Physical, it is generated by ADODB.Stream reading and BinaryWrite, is something miss setting about http header or etc.?

here are code about binary read:

```
<%
Response.Buffer = true
Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = "video/mp4"

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 1
objStream.LoadFromFile "file_real.mp4"

Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="download.mp4"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", 16815358
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
Response.Flush

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
%>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was found.

the server using HTTP_REFERER to check if the request is acceptable. In android system, when chrome play the audio/video file in html5 page, it pass the request to 'mediaserver' in system but without HTTP_REFERER, so the server block this request.

thank you anyway.